Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS Impress does not play Videos
The videos in my Impress slide show do not play any more. I think they stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I have not changed the videos, mostly MP4 files.
I’ve read and followed a lot of suggestions from other forums including:

Installing ubuntu-restricted-extras
Making sure the various gstreamer1-plugins good bad base ugly etc. codecs are present
Combinations of removing & installing gstreamer1.0-vaapi and clearing caches  rm -r ~/.cache/totem;  rm -r ~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/

I don’t know what mechanism Impress uses to play videos but assume it is not self contained as I believe VLC is which plays the videos quite happily.
Here’s some more clues when trying to play MP4 files...

mpv returns error Failed to recognize file format.
totem returns error ** Message: 10:33:44.010: Missing plugin: gstreamer|1.0|totem|text/html decoder|decoder-text/html (text/html decoder)

I’d be very grateful for any advice or suggestions.
Thanks

How was the upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04.1 done?

Amazingly David DE, I took notes. I was running 22.04 when my computer threw a hissy fit and refused to offer me a GUI so it was all done from the command line.  Briefly, first to 23.10 (sudo do-release-upgrade) then up to 24.04 with sudo do-release-upgrade -d. I still had problems but all seemed to be right after running sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop. That was all back in May and it has been running fine since. My use of Impress is seasonal so I’ve only just found the video problem.

Forcing the upgrade installed a version of Ubuntu with know issues. That is why the release was held back. 23.10 is past EOL so there was no supported path to that upgrade either. At this point I would say reinstall from scratch a fresh Ubuntu 24.04 and in a few weeks the update to 24.04.1 will be released.

Yes, I think you are right. I'd forgotten how I'd got to 24.04. Thanks, much appreciated.

I made it an answer if you want to up vote and accept it.

Before you reinstall, try sudo snap remove vlc && sudo apt install vlc, and let us know if it works. Sometimes, snap vlc refuses to play media files

Thanks for the suggestion Archisman Panigrahi but it didn't work.

A heads up for anyone that forces an update.
Forcing the upgrade installed a version of Ubuntu with know issues (as of this date). That is why the release was held back.
23.10 is past EOL so there was no supported path to that upgrade either.
At this point I would say reinstall from scratch a fresh Ubuntu 24.04 and in a few weeks the update to 24.04.1 will be released.
